# Unable to click the element by XPATH

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to click on **XML administration** element from following

```
<div id="sectionnav">
    <ul id="navlist" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">`enter code here`
    <li class="heading ui-accordion-li-fix">
    <a href="customer_main.do?showParam=Account Maintenance" class="MenuTitle ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>Account</a>
    <ul class="slide ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" style="height: 253px; display: none;">
    <li>
    <a href="/sher-link/user/UserProfileCustomerLoadAction.do">Modify Profile</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading ui-accordion-li-fix">
    <a href="#" class="MenuTitle ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"/>XML administration</a>
    <ul class="slide ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" role="tabpanel" style="height: 253px; display: block;">
    <li>
```

I tried following but getting element not found. Tried with using click by linktext as well but couldn't work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='navlist']/li[2]/a/text()")).click();

driver.findElement(By.linktext("XML administration")).click();
```

Comment: Is my xpath correct? can I use linktext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML you have displayed in your question is not well-formed (no closing tags), but I think the XPath you are looking for is:

```
//a[contains(.,'XML administration')]
```

The problem arises because the `span` tag in your XML doesn't actually contain any text, but is self-closing.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Xpath:-

```
//span[contains(.,'XML administration')]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Please get back to me if still facing any issue :)

Comment: Tried driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'XML administration')]")).click();    but getting an Error no such element  *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//span[contains(.,'XML administration')]}

Comment: Thanks  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(., 'XML administration')]")).click();   worked. Thanks everyone for the input